# Error messages with the 2sxc 11.07 LTS, Had an error talking to the server (status 405)

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I use DNN 9.8.0 new install, language (Swiss) German

If I want to delete an app (Gallery App v5) in the Manage Apps in Zone 2 this message comes after entering yes! in the browser:

Had an error talking to the server (status 405).
if you are an advanced user you can learn more about what went wrong - discover how on 2sxc.org/help?tag=debug

Something else about the browser:
Nothing is shown in Safarai 14.0.1 except the table, but there are no apps (empty field)
Sorry, i work with Safari and Mac...
I see the app in Firefox / Windows 10

The DNN log file shows me this:
2020-11-19 09:05:06.755+01:00 [vps74][D:2][T:8][ERROR] DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.Exceptions - FriendlyMessage="Fehler:  ist zur Zeit nicht verf�gbar." ctrl="ASP.desktopmodules_tosic_sexycontent_view_ascx" exc="System.ArgumentException: Ein Element mit dem gleichen Schl�ssel wurde bereits hinzugef�gt.

bei System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)

bei System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)

bei ToSic.Sxc.Cms.Publishing.PagePublishingResolverBase.Requirements(Int32 instanceId) in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Sxc\ToSic.Sxc\Cms\Publishing\PagePublishingResolverBase.cs:Zeile 20.

bei ToSic.Sxc.Cms.Publishing.PagePublishingResolverBase.GetPublishingState(Int32 instanceId) in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Sxc\ToSic.Sxc\Cms\Publishing\PagePublishingResolverBase.cs:Zeile 33.

bei ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.Run.DnnContext.Create(ISite site, IContainer container, IUser user, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, List`1 overrideParams) in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn\Dnn\Run\DnnInstanceContext.cs:Zeile 27.

bei ToSic.SexyContent.View.get_Block() in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.Main\View.ascx.cs:Zeile 21.

bei ToSic.SexyContent.View.EnsureCmsBlockAndPortalIsReady() in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.Main\View.ascx.Errors.cs:Zeile 19.

bei ToSic.SexyContent.View.<Page_Load>b__9_0() in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.Main\View.ascx.cs:Zeile 58.

bei ToSic.SexyContent.View.TryCatchAndLogToDnn(Action action, Action`1 timerWrap) in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Dnn.Main\View.ascx.Errors.cs:Zeile 44."

2020-11-19 17:54:22.986+01:00 [vps74][D:2][T:83][ERROR] DotNetNuke.Data.PetaPoco.PetaPocoHelper - [4] Error executing SQL: ;Exec dbo.AddFolder @0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8, @9, @10, @11, @12, @13

Verletzung der UNIQUE KEY-Einschr�nkung "IX_FolderPath". Ein doppelter Schl�ssel kann in das dbo.Folders-Objekt nicht eingef�gt werden. Der doppelte Schl�sselwert ist (0, adam/Gallery-Fancybox3/bVPOkkxHBEy4pYRDFHZMiw/).

Die Anweisung wurde beendet.

Nachtrag vom 20.11.2020, nach dem Upgrade auf 2sic 11.10.01

2020-11-20 09:36:56.701+01:00 [vps74][D:3][T:155][ERROR] DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.Exceptions - System.ArgumentException: Ein Element mit dem gleichen Schl�ssel wurde bereits hinzugef�gt.

bei System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)

bei System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)

bei ToSic.Eav.Data.LazyFastAccess.GetRepo(Int32 id) in C:\Projects\2sxc\eav-server\ToSic.Eav.Core\Data\Lists\LazyFastAccess.cs:Zeile 29.

bei ToSic.Eav.Data.LazyEntities.b__18_1(Nullable`1 l) in C:\Projects\2sxc\eav-server\ToSic.Eav.Core\Data\Entities\LazyEntities.cs:Zeile 150.

bei System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()

bei System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)

bei System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

bei ToSic.Eav.Data.LazyEntities.LoadEntities() in C:\Projects\2sxc\eav-server\ToSic.Eav.Core\Data\Entities\LazyEntities.cs:Zeile 143.

bei ToSic.Eav.Data.LazyEntities.GetEnumerator() in C:\Projects\2sxc\eav-server\ToSic.Eav.Core\Data\Entities\LazyEntities.cs:Zeile 132.

bei System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()

bei System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)

bei System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

bei ToSic.Sxc.Data.DynamicEntityWithList..ctor(IEntity parent, String field, IEnumerable`1 entities, String[] dimensions, Int32 compatibility, IBlock block) in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Sxc\ToSic.Sxc\Data\DynamicEntityWithList.cs:Zeile 28.

bei ToSic.Sxc.Data.DynamicEntity.GetEntityValue(String field) in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Sxc\ToSic.Sxc\Data\DynamicEntity.cs:Zeile 144.

bei ToSic.Sxc.Data.DynamicEntity.TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, Object& result) in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Sxc\ToSic.Sxc\Data\DynamicEntity.cs:Zeile 98.

bei CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )

bei ASP._Page_Portals_0_2sxc_Swiper__swiper_cshtml.Execute() in d:\WEB\EW-WEB\Portals\0\2sxc\Swiper_swiper.cshtml:Zeile 18.

bei System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()

bei System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)

bei ToSic.Sxc.Engines.RazorEngine.Render(TextWriter writer) in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Razor\Engines\Razor\RazorEngine.cs:Zeile 67.

bei ToSic.Sxc.Engines.RazorEngine.RenderTemplate() in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Dnn\ToSic.Sxc.Razor\Engines\Razor\RazorEngine.cs:Zeile 77.

bei ToSic.Sxc.Engines.EngineBase.Render() in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Sxc\ToSic.Sxc\Engines\EngineBase.cs:Zeile 148.

bei ToSic.Sxc.Blocks.BlockBuilder.Render() in C:\Projects\2sxc\2sxc\Src\Sxc\ToSic.Sxc\Blocks\BlockBuilder_Render.cs:Zeile 57.

Comment: problem solved: https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues/2205

...
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>

...
      <remove name="WebDAV" />
    </handlers>

Comment: see below regarding credit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do I get "answer" credit if my Issue contains the answwer? :)

[Cannot Delete Things](https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues/2205) - API, Extensionless URI handler overridden by WebDAV